# Using UNION ALL on 2 tables to obtain specific results

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, view, union-all

I am attempting to query unique results but am having issues with **Query 2** as it pulls the Top 1 result of any ItemNumber instead of my desired ItemNumber from my select statement. I want to display all unique results from **Query 1** & I want to display only 1 unique result from **Query 2** where NULL Locations are prioritized. (1 'Y' SpecialItem associated per ItemNumber. I have mocked up a small example of my issue to keep the question from being too complex.

**Table being used:**

```
CREATE TABLE QA_TESTING (
    ItemNumber varchar(255),
    ItemName varchar(255),
    Location varchar(255)
)
```

**Data being used:**

```
Insert into QA_Testing (ItemNumber, ItemName, Location) Values ('333', 'Apple', 'USA')
Insert into QA_Testing (ItemNumber, ItemName, Location) Values ('501', 'Apple', NULL)
Insert into QA_Testing (ItemNumber, ItemName, Location) Values ('501', 'Apple', NULL)
Insert into QA_Testing (ItemNumber, ItemName, Location) Values ('501', 'Apple', 'USA')
Insert into QA_Testing (ItemNumber, ItemName, Location) Values ('501', 'Apple', NULL)
Insert into QA_Testing (ItemNumber, ItemName, Location) Values ('405', 'Apple', 'USA')
Insert into QA_Testing (ItemNumber, ItemName, Location) Values ('405', 'Orange', 'USA')
Insert into QA_Testing (ItemNumber, ItemName, Location) Values ('501', 'Apple', 'USA')
```

**My View:**

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME 
           FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
           WHERE  TABLE_NAME = N'QA_TESTING_VW')
        DROP VIEW QA_TESTING_VW
    GO
    
    CREATE VIEW dbo.QA_TESTING_VW
    AS
    (
    
    (
    --Query 1
    Select DISTINCT QAT.ItemNumber, QAT.ItemName, Null AS SpecialItem, QAT.Location
    From QA_Testing QAT
    Where ItemName = 'Apple'
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
    --I Want to prioritize to show NULL over a non-null location in second query. If there is a null, show the null, otherwise, show the populated location. Only 1 row should be returned.
    --Query 2 
    Select DISTINCT TOP 1 QAT.ItemNumber, QAT.ItemName, 'Y' AS SpecialItem, QAT.Location
    From QA_Testing QAT
    Where ItemName = 'Apple'
    --ORDER BY Location ASC    --ORDER BY TAKES TOO LONG
    )
    
    ) 
    GO
```

**My Select Statement:**

```
--This has to stay in a simple format like so, with no additional unions, joins, etc.
Select * from QA_TESTING_VW where ItemNumber in ('501','830')
```

**Outcome:**

[image]

**Expected Outcome:**

[image: ExpectedOutcome]

Comment: Aren't the two halves of the union just doing the same thing? They have the same `WHERE` filter

Comment: @Charlieface this is just a mocked up example, the two where clauses are substantially different. I just didn't want to overcomplicate anyone with a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

there is comment "ORDER BY TAKES TOO LONG"

that's why I'm not quite sure.
As fuel for thought:

```
Select distinct QAT.ItemNumber, QAT.ItemName, O.SpecialItem, QAT.[Location]
From
    (
        Select QAT.ItemNumber
            ,QAT.ItemName
            ,QAT.[Location]
            ,row_number() over(partition by QAT.ItemNumber, QAT.ItemName order by QAT.[Location]) as LocationPriority
        From QA_Testing QAT
        Where ItemName = 'Apple'
    ) QAT
    left join
    (
        select 'Y' AS SpecialItem
        union all
        select null
    ) O
    on QAT.LocationPriority = 1
```